# React Native Scroll View not showing image

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

The below is my code of react native app code. But its not showing the image. i Moved the container style from scroll view to image the the image showed in an incorrect way.

```
<ScrollView vertical={true} style={styles.container} >
  <Image
    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.PassedURL }}>
  </Image>
</ScrollView>
```

here the container style

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'gray',
  padding: 10
},
```

There is nothing other to render on the screen

Comment: Does it render without scroll?

Comment: Can you try manually specifying the dimensions? Rather than setting them to `100%`? eg, `width: 200, height: 200`

Comment: @Nerius Jok Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `flex:1` in `ScrollView`, if that doesn't fix it try to set specific width and height as suggested by others

```
<ScrollView vertical={true} style={styles.container} >
   <Image
     style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
     source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.PassedURL }}>
    />
</ScrollView>
```

The container style

```
container: {
  backgroundColor: 'gray',
  padding: 10
},
```

**EDIT:**

If you want it to fill to full width just set width to 100% and the height will be ajusted accordingly and maybe put resizeMode="contain" or "cover" depending on your need

Comment: This doesn't work as I need responsive sizing, I don't know the height or width of the image, I just want the image to span the full width, while keeping aspect ratio for the height

Comment: if you want it to fill to full width just set with to 100% and the height will be ajusted accordingly and maybe put resizeMode="contain" or "cover" depending on your need @conor909

Answer (score 1):

it is because you configure image height and weight with percentage

```
<Image
    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.PassedURL }}>
</Image>
```

try to set it with exact number ,percentage only work with only one width or heigth not both

```
<Image
    style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
    source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.PassedURL }}>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```js
function getAspectRatio(img) {
    const data = Image.resolveAssetSource(img);
    return data.width / data.height;
}

...

<ScrollView horizontal={true} >
    <Image source={img} resizeMode='contain' 
        style={{ 
            height: '100%', 
            width: undefined, 
            aspectRatio: getAspectRatio(img) 
        }}
    />
</ScrollView>
```

It has the height of the view and preserves the aspect ratio of the image.